# How to get name attribute in a form helper with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, ruby-on-rails-6

For many lengthy reasons I want to be able to do something like this in a form builder:

```rb
<%= form_with model: resource, local: true, builder: CustomBuilder do |form| %>
  <input <%= form.tag_name :body %> ref="input"></input>
  <%= form.label :body %>
<% end %>
```

and get the name attribute like that (to not construct it myself)

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```rb
class CustomBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def tag_name object
    fragment = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(self.text_field(object)). children [0]
    "name='#{fragment.attributes["name"]}'"
  end
end
```

But I'm wondering if there is a better way... Also it would be cool to extract all generated attributes from a field (like the value) if someone has some ideas...

I know about the existence of `tag_name` in `Tag::Base`, but I am not able to call it without modifing the rails' codebase (at least as far as I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is much better:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def tag_name_for(method)
    ActionView::Helpers::Tags::TextField.new(object_name, method, {}).send(:tag_name)
  end
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_with model: resource, local: true do |f| %>
  <input name="<%= f.tag_name_for(:body) %>" ref="input"></input>
<% end %>
```